# MySQL Query Using JSON_CONTAINS

Tags: mysql, json

I have a MySQL 5.7 table which includes a column of type VARCHAR named 'area' which contains JSON data. For example
["BS20","BS21"]

I need to search on that table to find the first row containing a particular string. The string is contained in a variable like

```
$area = BS20;
```

and I have tried this for my query

```
SELECT * FROM aedv2_admin WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(area,'$area')=1
```

and I get an error

Invalid JSON text in argument 2 to function json_contains: "Invalid value." at position 0.12

For testing I have tried hard coding argument 2 as BS20 and 'BS20' but neither helps. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *and I have tried this for my query* Provide query text, not a part cut off the PHP code.

Comment: Use JSON_SEACRCH(). Or `'$area'` after the substitution must give `'"BS20"'`. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=cebe831da6f25911384813f72dafedf7

Answer (score 1):

Phew! That was a bit painful, but with thanks to Akina my final code ended up like this

```
$area = '\"'.$_POST['area'].'\"';

$query_sponsor = "SELECT * FROM aedv2_admin WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(area,'$area')";
```